# Is my PHP code vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, php, xss

Users in this website use a tool that build a JavaScript object with custom settings.

Every time they change something in the input elements i want to execute this javascript code with their own settings and show a preview.

So i put an iframe that send a request with the settings in the url.

```
<iframe src="settings.php?javascript=...></iframe>
```

Every time they change something the iframe is reloaded.

My PHP code?

```
<?php

$javascript = "";

/**/

if(empty($_GET["javascript"]))
{
    exit;
}

/**/

$javascript = "

    <script>
        ".$_GET["javascript"]."
    </script>

";

/**/

$html = '

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            '.$javascript.'
        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>

';

/**/

echo($html);
```

Is this code vulnerable to XSS? if yes, how can i prevent this?

Comment: If you let people insert any javascript they want, they can put an exploit and share the link. How can you prevent this? Don't let people run their own javascripts on your website.

Comment: Quite simply: `settings.php?javascript=alert%28%22I+am+vulnerable%22%29%3B` so yes, quite vulnerable.

Comment: just saying: they can put a lot more than javascript very easily. Also, yes, NEVER let people run JS on other machines.

settings.php?javascript=</script><h1>Lol I can write anything, maybe even ask for user password and stuff without needing to know the internal structure of the iframe</h1><script>andICanStillWriteJSToUseOnThePreviousHTML()

Comment: Keh, you can make it secure, but it's **very** hard to do that than simply prevent others running their javascript code on your webpage. You can sandbox it. Or implement CSP...

Comment: If i pass only the JSON object it need some filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is vulnerable to XSS. In fact, letting users run arbitrary javascript is pretty much the definition of an XSS vulnerability. The fact that it's intentional instead of accidental doesn't make it less vulnerable.

If all you want is an object of settings, there's no reason to allow arbitrary javascript when you can just use JSON . JSON.parse will parse a JSON string into a JS object (and JSON.stringify will serialize an object to a string) in javascript. Using the JSON methods will do extra validation to ensure that the object is a valid JSON object/string over directly putting it in a script tag (or using eval), preventing (at least this one venue of) XSS.